# YouTube Autoplay Issue

Tags: youtube, autoplay

I am trying to get an embedded YouTube video to autoplay. I have set the ?autoplay=1 in the parameter but this seems to be deprecated. I have not been able to find any documentation on it though.

How can I get autoplay to work on videos?

```
<iframe class="iframe-vid" width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/Bey4XXJAqS8?autoplay=1&enablejsapi=1" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen=""></iframe>
```

Comment: If you're having this issue in Google Chrome, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50323662/4092887) might help you.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't mind that the video autoplays muted, you can add the following parameter in the YouTube URL:

```
&rel=0&mute=1
```

Here is the iframe with autoplay enabled and muted<sup>1</sup>

```
<iframe class="iframe-vid" width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/Bey4XXJAqS8?autoplay=1&enablejsapi=1&rel=0&mute=1" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen=""></iframe>
```

- Test made in Google Chrome Version 72.0.3626.119 (Build oficial) (32 bits)

---

<sup>1</sup> I really don't know why the "mute" option must be set in the URL *(and only in Google Chrome)*, because in Firefox and Edge the video autoplays without adding the `mute` parameter.

Answer (score -1):

In order for the autoplay=1 to work, you must put the single quotation mark after the "1" and a space. Works perfect after.

ex. autoplay=1"