# Play embed youtube after preloader screen fade out

Tags: javascript, jquery, youtube

I'm trying to make a iframe Youtube plays after my preloaded screen fade out. Currently, I'm using jQuery to fade out the preloader screen.

Which I'm using this code there

```
$(window).on("load", function () {
    $('.pre-loader').fadeOut(1000);
});
```

Somehow his set of code can't run if I insert this in the windows.on load function. I have to place it outside the window.on load function. Couldn't understand why.

```
var tag = document.createElement('script');
tag.src = 'https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api';
var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

var player;
function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
    player = new YT.Player('existing-iframe-example', {
        events: {
            'onReady': onPlayerReady,
            'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
        }
    });
}
function onPlayerReady(event) {
    console.log('player ready');
    event.target.playVideo();

}
function onPlayerStateChange(event) {
    console.log('event change')
}
```

This is how the iframe code I'm using in my html

```
<iframe id="existing-iframe-example" class="yt-video" 
src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/niRUIXag55I?enablejsapi=1&rel=0" frameborder="0" 
allow="accelerometer; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" 
allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

In my console.log, I can see 'player ready' and 'event change'. But the youtube video just can't play.

Any help here will be deeply appreciated.

Comment: Check [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54912914/4092887).