# Embed youtube video doesn't autoplay with audio

Tags: html, wordpress, video, embed, autoplay

After checking out other posts on embedding videos that didn't help fix my issue, I seek some suggestion in making the video autoplay along with the audio as the page is visited. Below is the code embedded into my WordPress page [here](https://dev-packed-with-purpose.pantheonsite.io/test-video-page/).

```
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/ikTEJCk0Da0" title="YouTube video player" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

I did use query string like `https://www.youtube.com/embed/ikTEJCk0Da0?autoplay=1` but it just makes the progress bar move but the video.

I did also use https://www.classynemesis.com/projects/ytembed/ to get the link, but it didn't help either.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [YouTube Autoplay Issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54889615/youtube-autoplay-issue)

Comment: But I need autoplay with audio. The post you directed me to solves just the autoplay, not the audio part. Changing mute=0 fails autoplay.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Modern browsers don't allow autoplay with audio on b/c it's considered annoying.

There are some not-easy-ways to cheat them, but only with self-hosted videos (no YouTube/Vimeo).

Moreover there's no guarantee those methods will not stop working abruptly. Indeed they will stop abruptly soon or later (along with browsers' updates) so that new methods have to be deployed again and again.

I suggest to give up the idea.

P.S.
I agree with browsers' developers: audio autoplay IS ANNOYING.

Comment: Thanks for the knowledge, this is very helpful in saving my time from unnecessary googling out for solutions.

Answer (score 0):

I have it working, using embed and adding two other output controls:

https://www.youtube.com/embed/zzzzgRUUj1FQ?autoplay=1&controls=0
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
(This is a fake URL; supply your own)

If controls are not displayed (=0), it appears that is what causes it to allow to play. The player, of course, goes full screen (due to using /embed/).  You cannot change the screen at all, but you can start and stop the video. I have found good use for this now that I figured it out.