# How to autoplay embed youtube video

Tags: youtube, embed, autoplay

I'm trying to set embed youtube video to auto play but nothing works unless i make it muted

```
<iframe id="yt_vid" width="100%" height="450px" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/<?=yt_code?>?autoplay=1&mute=1" frameborder="0" allow="autoplay encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Is there any code working on chrome and firefox?

Comment: Check the answers given to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50290601/4092887).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Youtube iframe src autoplay not working in chrome browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50290601/youtube-iframe-src-autoplay-not-working-in-chrome-browser)