# Webview video (iframe) does not play unless sound is muted

Tags: java, android-studio, video, iframe, webview

I am trying to play an IFRAME video using webview in android java, The video loads correctly but refuses to play unless the sound is muted. Please any help on this. This is my webView code:

```
private void playVideoOnWebView(String videoUrl) {
        videoWebViewPlayer = findViewById(R.id.videoPlayerWebView);           
        videoWebViewPlayer.setVisibility(VISIBLE);
        videoWebViewPlayer.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);    
        videoWebViewPlayer.getSettings().getAllowContentAccess();
        videoWebViewPlayer.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
        videoWebViewPlayer.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled(true);videoWebViewPlayer.getSettings().setAppCachePath(getApplicationContext().getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath() + "/cache");
        videoWebViewPlayer.getSettings().setDatabaseEnabled(true);
        videoWebViewPlayer.getSettings().setDatabasePath(getApplicationContext().getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath() + "/databases");
        videoWebViewPlayer.getSettings().setPluginState(WebSettings.PluginState.ON);
        videoWebViewPlayer.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
        videoWebViewPlayer.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
        videoWebViewPlayer.loadUrl(videoUrl);
    }
```

and this is the iframe from the web page

```html
 <iframe id="iframe" style="width: 100%; border-width: 0px; height: 100%;" src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/259666821?loop=false&amp;byline=false&amp;portrait=false&amp;title=false&amp;speed=true&amp;transparent=1&amp;gesture=media" allowfullscreen="" allowtransparency="" allow="autoplay"></iframe>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Youtube iframe src autoplay not working in chrome browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50290601/youtube-iframe-src-autoplay-not-working-in-chrome-browser)

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation, but it did not answer my question. The video is meant to play in android webview not a browser

Comment: Could you share your code? then we can start from there.

Comment: @Pankwood I just did that.

Answer (score 0):

There is a convention on web/mobile standards where auto-play videos should be muted. It prevents disturbance, for example, you open a website or app and it starts to play something, but you are in a meeting.

> "Remember that audio tracks that render silence are still audio
> tracks, and their existence affects whether a video will auto-play at
> all. In these cases, a video with silent audio tracks won’t play. The
> audio track should be removed or, alternatively, the muted attribute
> can be set on the media element.

References:

https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/09/autoplay-policy-changes

https://webkit.org/blog/7734/auto-play-policy-changes-for-macos/

https://vimeo.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/115004485728-Autoplaying-e-looping-v%C3%ADdeos-incorporados